# Set up Nginx with multiple React projects

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have been trying to set up nginx to post 2 react projects.
I would like it to work like it works on regular location \ { } where it uses the react project routes from location.

e.g.

```
location / {
    root   /var/www/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

And from there it uses React project routes.
e.g.

```
  <Routes>
    <Route path='*' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>
```

So when I enter IP in the browser : 255.255.255.255/anything it goes to => 255.255.255.255/home

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Here is what i've got: 
Config:

```
location /site1/ {
    root   /var/www/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
location /site2/ {
    root   /var/www/html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Dir structure: `/var/www/html` has 2 dir `site1` and `site2` that are build versions of respective React projects (build folder renamed to `site1` and `site2`)
Now that I go to `255.255.255.255/site1/` it just displays the default nginx index page.
The further routes do not work either. I would like it go from `255.255.255.255/site1` to `255.255.255.255/site1/home` (e.g. start form /site1/ as a starting location)


Also if I Don't use routes in my React project but make App.js as a page => upon entering `255.255.255.255/site1/index.html` manually it opens the page. (Don't like the idea of someone needing to enter the index.html in the link)


Any help Appreciated,
Thank you for reading all of this

Comment: The final parameter of the `try_files` statement needs to point to the correct `index.html` file. For example: `/site1/index.html` and not `/index.html` which is probably the default Nginx welcome page.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just added `try_files $uri /site1/index.html;` => This works great and opens the index page when using regular html file and with React project where App.js is set up as a page, **BUT** sadly the React project where Routes are used it just can't seem to find the right path. In conclusion I now am pretty sure `try_files`  part has to be the one that needs some work :) -Thank you